# thymeleaf & spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf to return the index.html file but it doesn't work. It doesn't return the index page but only returns 1 span. I want to return the correct index.html file, what should I do? I return "index" but when run again there is only one span tag

Here is controller file

```
package com.example.warehouse.controller;
import com.example.warehouse.dto.OrderDTO;
import com.example.warehouse.dto.OrderListDTO;
import com.example.warehouse.dto.ResponseCommonDTO;
import com.example.warehouse.services.WareHouseServices;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class WarehouseController {

    @Autowired
    WareHouseServices wareHouseServices;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String myView1() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping ("/home")
    public String myView(Model model) {
        List<OrderListDTO> orderListDTOS = wareHouseServices.displayOrderList();
        model.addAttribute("order", orderListDTOS);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

My View

<h1>Welcome to My View</h1>
<p>This is a sample view without using a template engine.</p>
<ul>
<li>
 <span th:text="*{order.getIdOrder()}"></span> : <span th:text="*{order.getIdWarehouse()}">  </span> 
</li>
</ul>
```

[The result when accessing `/home`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j4pk.png)

I want to return the content of the `index.html` file

Answer (score 0):

Annotating the controller with `@RestController` makes the controller trying to return the content directly inside the response body. You can configure your RestController return in many ways like e.g. using `ResponseEntity`. Also, Spring MVC tries to convert the data automatically.

```java
@RestController
public class WarehouseController {

    //...
}
```

But what you want is to return an HTML page through a Thymeleaf view. To do so, you must have Thymeleaf properly set up and annotate the Controller with `@Controller`. This way Spring MVC knows to process the request through ModelAndView.

A model is then always in play and if you only return a String, Spring will try to find a view with that specific name. You can also configure this behavior further, e.g. when returning `ModelAndView` instead of a String.

```java
@Controller
public class WarehouseController {

    //...
}
```

Comment: I fixed it thank you

Comment: So what was it?